# grant permission for normal user to run fdisk

Tags: ubuntu

i have a user named "tony" which do not have permission to use command fdisk, so i do like this:

```
vim /etc/sudoers

# add the following line
tony ALL=(root) /sbin/fdisk
```

after that, I convert back to `tony`, and run command `fdisk -l`, but i still get the following errors: do not have enough permission,

but when i run command `sudo -l`, i can get this:

```
(root) /sbin/fdisk
```

I am a little confued why user tony still haven't permission to run `fdisk`?

Comment: What command did you run with `sudo`? The entry in `sudoers` has to match the command you actually use.

Comment: Don't ever use `vim /etc/sudoers` - always use `visudo` as it does syntax checking for you too

Answer (score 2):

When `/etc/sudoers` is used to grant permission to run some command as a particular user (often as `root`), the user will still need to prefix that command with `sudo`. In other words you should run `sudo fdisk -l` instead of just `fdisk -l`.

Because `sudo` is a security-critical tool, it may even require you to specify the **actual** path of the permitted command and not a path that includes symbolic links. In a fresh install of RHEL 8, the classic `/bin` and `/sbin` directories have been replaced with symlinks to `/usr/bin` and `/usr/sbin` respectively.

You might want to run `realpath /sbin/fdisk` and see what it reports: if it says `/usr/sbin/fdisk`, then you should specify the `sudoers` line as:

```
tony ALL=(root) /usr/sbin/fdisk
```

Comment: FWIW it's `/sbin/fdisk` on my Pi

Comment: @roaima on Ubuntu it is under `/usr/sbin/`.